# Alternative method for NSURLRequest's private "setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:forHost:"?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsurlrequest, iphone-privateapi

My iPhone application was rejected solely for using the (very safe, it seems) private method `+setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:forHost:` for [`NSURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/index.html). Is there a non-private API to emulate this functionality?

Comment: Why do you want to allow invalid HTTPs certificates in the first place?

Comment: Hi.. your issue is resolved but for that have you exclude above method in your source code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be a public API for that ;)
[How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert/2033823#2033823)

Comment: Thank you! Strange that Google didn't turn up this.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I'm testing with 10.6.8 and this code still works -- it's using the private API but checking that the selector exists (myurl is the NSURL I'm trying to load into a WebView or an NSURLConnection):

```
SEL selx = NSSelectorFromString(@"setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:forHost:");
if ( [NSURLRequest respondsToSelector: selx] )
{
    IMP fp;

    fp = [NSURLRequest methodForSelector:selx];

    (fp)([NSURLRequest class], selx, YES, [myurl host]);
}
```

Note that "@selector" wasn't used so that absolutely *all* the work would be done at runtime. That makes it about as safe and as hidden from Apple's checks as can be, especially if you obscure the string.

Comment: Not a recommended solution: (1) you don't give your user the option to accept or not.  (2) You're writing in a public forum if Apple happens upon it they might get wise to it.  (3) See Yonel's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2145367/818352

Comment: Just wanted to say that this worked for me until the 5S and iPad Air came out - crashes here (on the cast) on either of those devices.

Answer (score 1):

One really stupid workaround is to make your own category method:

```
@implementation NSURLRequest (IgnoreSSL)

+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

This should get by Apple's private API checks, but it's still the same thing (using a private, undocumented API[1] that is liable to break at any time). Actually, it's worse since it allows everything, not just that host.

[1]: An private API that *should* be made public, but a private API nevertheless.

Comment: From what I know of it, this will still not pass Apple's checks, as they appear to use a rather simple analysis based purely on selectors, not their usage.

Comment: @Mike: Are you sure? I am not "using" the selector at all, only redefining it. It is Apple's internals that call it. Granted, this is not at all safe, but I don't see how it wouldn't pass Apple's checks.

Comment: This way will definitely get your app rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a suggestion. Have you thought about using [ASIHttpRequest Framework](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree) for this? This framework is complete in all aspects. Check the documentation, maybe it can help you too.

Answer (score 0):

setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate  seems to now be unsupported in OS X 10.6.6 altogether.

Did I say 10.6.6?   Perhaps I should have said "Snow Vista".