# Byte datatype in Objective C in iPhone

Tags: iphone, byte, types

I want to send the bytes to the server. So i donno Which data types is used for bytes. I have used "%s" and sent the bytes to the server. But In server side they have received 6 bytes only. But my case i want to send 32 bytes to the server. So Which data type is used for that?

EDIT:-

Here my sample code is,

```
 -(void)sendDevice:(NSData *)data // data value comes 32 bytes.
 {
       NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://MyserverURL.php?Dataid=%????",[data bytes]];

       NSURL *urlToSend2 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

       NSURLRequest *urlRequest2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToSend2              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:50];                                                     

       NSURLConnection *theconnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest2 delegate:self]; 

      [theconnection start];

 }
```

Please Guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: %s makes it a string, danger! strings terminate at a 0 byte in C (and Objective C as well) so maybe you had 6 nonzero bytes and one 0 next, e.g. Not all characters can safely appear in URL's (that's why we have url-encoding/quoting), so %s is not a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

`NSData` is the class that generally is used for byte data. take a look at its documentation and see if thats what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used NSData and sent the bytes to the server. In my case, NSData value is [data bytes], How can i post to the server, NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://InMy serverurl.com/DTid=%????",[data bytes]];

Answer (score 1):

As Jesse suggests, raw bytes are best stored in an NSData instance.  For transmission to your web server, you'll probably want to create a Base64-encoded string representation of the NSData's bytes.  For that, I recommend either of the categories present at the bottom of [this CocoaDev wiki page](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour).

Answer (score 1):

Look like u use POST data to the server?

Like:-----

```
- (Boolean) pushSync: (NSString *) fromContext ToContext: (NSString *) toContext
{

    Boolean success = FALSE;

    NSString *exported = [self exportData: fromContext ToContext: toContext];

    if( exported != nil )
    {

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [self getPushURL]];

        if( request != nil )

        {

           NSURLResponse * response = nil;

           NSError * error = nil;

           [request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

           NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

           [postBody appendData:[exporteddataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

           [request setHTTPBody:postBody];

           [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

           NSData *xmlResult = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];   

           if( xmlResult )

           {
            [self parseXMLResult:xmlResult];

              if([replyStatus isEqualToString:@"true"])

                success = TRUE;
          }
      }

  }

   return success;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are trying to POST data to the server?

look at this question it might be similar and provide the answer

[Sending POST data from iphone over SSL HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571336/sending-post-data-from-iphone-over-ssl-https)

Answer (score 0):

If you use arbitrary data, first hexify it and then use %s. On the server side you can decode it on reception. So basically do a repeated sprintf with format "%02x" and append these.
In that case it will survive inside url-strings, after the ? as in your example.

Comment: to comment on myself: I saw the Base64 suggestion below (which is more efficient) but I avoided it because the standard alphabet contains /,
but I saw in the link you can specify your own, cool!