# How to send data from iphone to server using the url

Tags: php, iphone, xcode, url, nsurlconnection

I wish to know how i can send data from my iphone app to a table in mysql server using the url.

http://localhost/location.php?id=&latitude=@&longitude=@

where the "@" are the latitude and longitude variables from xcode.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571336/sending-post-data-from-iphone-over-ssl-https

Answer (score 0):

hi friend 
for this you need to set connection first using ASIHttp Connection Delegate

Answer (score 0):

The most common means of interacting with a server in this manner are via the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)  `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` method (and other related methods in NSString) and the [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, which is capable of performing asynchronous background requests.

Both of the above linked class reference documents contain code samples (see the "Related sample code" section at the top of each).

Additionally, there are 3rd party solutions available, such as the commonly used [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) class.

Once the data "hits" the server, you'd then retrieve the data from the [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) superglobal prior to storing it in the database table. There are a wide variety of approaches to this (using an abstraction layer such as [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), etc.) so it really depends on your personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code
First you might have import asihttprequest package and all the required frameworks.after that

```
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASINetworkQueue.h"
```

In your viewcontroller.h file

```
ASINetworkQueue  *networkQueue;
```

In your viewController.m file:-
in viewdidLoad:-

```
networkQueue=[[ASINetworkQueue queue]retain];
```

Write the following code where you want to send the request:-

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/location.php?id=&latitude=%@&longitude=%@",latitude,longitude];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
        [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request setDidFinishSelector: @selector(*writemethodforsuccessfulrequest*)];
        [request setDidFailSelector: @selector(*writemethodforrequestfailed*)];
        [networkQueue addOperation: request];
        [networkQueue go];
```

In dealloc:-

```
[networkQueue cancelAllOperations];
[networkQueue release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple
Try this

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/location.php?id=&latitude=%@&longitude=%@",yourLat,yourLong];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
NSData *returnData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
// returnData will be the response you get when you pass the URL. If you like to 
// get some acknowledgement pass a xml format with some parameters to check 
// whether the URL you sent is valid one.
```